# Why is SetThreadAffinityMask ignored?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, setthreadaffinitymask

Why is SetThreadAffinityMask ignored?
I'm trying to write a program that sets the Affinity of each process thread according to the value of IdealProcessor.
But SetThreadAffinityMask is ignored.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ThreadAffinity
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetThreadIdealProcessorEx(IntPtr hThread, ref PROCESSOR_NUMBER lpIdealProcessor);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PROCESSOR_NUMBER
        {
            public ushort Group;
            public byte Number;
            public byte Reserved;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum ThreadAccess : int
        {
            TERMINATE = (0x0001),
            SUSPEND_RESUME = (0x0002),
            GET_CONTEXT = (0x0008),
            SET_CONTEXT = (0x0010),
            SET_INFORMATION = (0x0020),
            QUERY_INFORMATION = (0x0040),
            SET_THREAD_TOKEN = (0x0080),
            IMPERSONATE = (0x0100),
            DIRECT_IMPERSONATION = (0x0200),
            THREAD_ALL_ACCESS = (0x1F03FF)
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter process id:");
            int processId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
            {
                IntPtr hThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.QUERY_INFORMATION, false, (uint)thread.Id);
                PROCESSOR_NUMBER processorNumber = new PROCESSOR_NUMBER();
                GetThreadIdealProcessorEx(hThread, ref processorNumber);
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} ideal processor is {1}", thread.Id, processorNumber.Number);
                SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, (IntPtr)(1 << processorNumber.Number));
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't deny that with 99% probability I'm an idiot, that's why I came here to ask for your help.

upd1: The program properly detects idealprocessor, but doesn't set affinity to the thread.

Comment: Check the results of your API calls. How do you determine that the call is ignored - why would the thread not already be running on the processor that the O/S thought was ideal?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, if I look at threads affinity in process hacker, I see that all processors are enabled, not those that are considered ideal.

Comment: You don't do any error checking. You must sort that our first. Setting affinity is likely to make your program perform worse than letting the system decide. So far as I can tell, this code would be a disaster on a machine with multiple processor groups, i.e. a NUMA machine or one with more than 64 processors.

Comment: Per documentation: [This handle must have the THREAD_SET_INFORMATION or THREAD_SET_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right and the THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION or THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, at this point I am only making this program for my personal use.

Comment: @RaymondChen, doesn't THREAD_ALL_ACCESS give all these rights?

Comment: It does. But you didn't use THREAD_ALL_ACCESS.

Comment: @RaymondChen, ahahahahahahaha, man, I'm so dumb. Thanks, for the help) Thanks for pointing out my mistake now.

Comment: Error checking would have helped find this problem much faster than posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

As [@RaymondChen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) said

> Per documentation: This handle must have the THREAD_SET_INFORMATION or
> THREAD_SET_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right and the
> THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION or THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access
> right.